# Pushserver isn't waiting for promise answer

Tags: server, promise, async-await, notifications, push

I have this push server which sends push notifications to devices and logs the response to a json. The code goes:

**push.js**

```
module.exports.sendPushSubscription = async (post, recipient, p256, auth) => {
    console.log("Mandando PUSHES");
    const subscription = {
        endpoint: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/${recipient}`,
        expirationTime: null,
        keys: {
          p256dh: `${p256}`,
          auth: `${auth}`
        }
      }
    console.log(subscription);
 
    error = webpush.sendNotification(subscription, JSON.stringify(post))
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Notificación enviada");
            return "Sent!";
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
 
    await Promise.all(error);
 
    return error;
};
```

**routes.js**

```
recipients = recipients.split(',');
p256 = p256.split(',');
auth = auth.split(',');
let err = "";
 
for(var i=0;i<recipients.length;i++) {
  err = "Trying";
  err = push.sendPushSubscription(post, recipients[i], p256[i], auth[i]);
  post.recipients.push({
    recipient: recipients[i],
    error: err
  })
}
rsp.json(post);
```

However, despite the code might suggest the **sendPushSubscription** function should wait for the promises to end (it's usually only one) and return either **Sent!** or the error **itself**, the json always adds the recipient and an empty error. No matter if it succeeds or fails, the answer is:

```
"recipients": [
    {
        "recipient": "d96UkANUtAo:APA91bF1-...",
        "error": {}
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Emiliano

Comment: Hint: `err` is a Promise, not an error.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant, Roamer.